# Symfony, Twig, if conditions for tab highlights according to current route

Tags: twig, symfony

I am trying to get a list to highlight if it is at its current page (route). However, I also have subpages within the pages of which I also want the list to be highlighted.

I have my menu if statements:

```
 <ul class="menu">
                {% if app.request.get('_route') == 'home' %}
                    <li class="current"><a href="{{ path('home')}}">Home</a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li><a href="{{ path('home')}}">Home</a></li>
                {% endif %}

                {% if app.request.get('_route') == 'reports' %}
                    <li class="current"><a href="{{ path('reports') }}">Reports</a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li><a href="{{ path('reports') }}">Reports</a></li>
                {% endif %}

// etc etc
```

Now in my reports page, the route is /reports/ I have a menu that clicks to "Detail", "Summary", etc it will go to /reports/detail and /reports/summary... I want it so that when users click on those links, the main navigation is still highlighted.

I was wondering if there is an if statement condition something like this:

```
{% if app.request.get('_route') starts with(?) 'reports' %}
```

So whenever anyone goes to a route that's a sub page of /reports/, the "Reports" li in the menu will still be highlighted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if twig has a function for "starts with" but you can check for containment using `in`

```
{% if 'reports' in app.request.get('_route')  %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this question with current information.
As per current (2.x) Twig documentation this is possible the way it is asked for.
To be more specific, [the documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#comparisons) states:

> You can also check if a string starts with or ends with another string:

```
{% if 'Fabien' starts with 'F' %}
{% endif %}
{% if 'Fabien' ends with 'n' %}
{% endif %}
```

As such, the desired expression is perfectly possible:

```
{% if app.request.get('_route') starts with 'reports' %}
```

And works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good choices on this thread but another option is to pass the route into an array. This is useful if you have dropdown menu items.

> The items in the array would be your defined routes.

```
{% set routes = {
'activities':
    [
        'walking',
        'swimming',
        'running'
    ]
} %}
```

Then in your menu bar add this to your menu label class.

```
{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') in routes.activities %} Do Something {% endif %}
```